# How to rename service in docker compose override?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have a couple of services `web1` and `web2` and I can spin them up in prod or dev

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

Now let's say I do the same for a testing config. If my test yml were only changing the container name, for example,

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  web1:
    container_name: web1_test
  web2:
    container_name: web2_test
```

and I had my web services already running, then this would recreate the services, effectively replacing their containers with new ones bearing the new config (in this case a new name). But I'd rather not, it'd be nice to just spin them up and down without interfering with the originals.

A better experience would be

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  web1:
    service_name: web1_test
  web2:
    service_name: web2_test
```

then I could start the test versions and stop them without touching the originals.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d web1_test web2_test
```

Is there any way to leave the original services up and spin up some new test instances with a simple config overlay?

---

Note: I'm currently using `docker-compose run` to meet my needs. In practice I'm also modifying env variables and ports likes so:

```
docker-compose -f Docker/docker-compose.yml -f Docker/docker-compose.dev.yml run -d --name web1_test -e VAR1=web1_test_var -p 5001:5000 web1
```

so I already know 'how to get it done', I'm looking more for, am I missing a better way to accomplish the same? It'd be nice to have the port and env and name stuff in a config wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `container_name` per service you could use different project names for the same `docker-compose.yml` using the flag: `-p, --project-name NAME`.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p foo up -d
foo_web_1
foo_web_2

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p bar up -d
bar_web_1
bar_web_2
```

Comment: This seems like the sort of answer I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to get it to behave the same as my `docker-compose run --name test_web -p etc`. I get port and name collisions in spite of my test.yaml changing them. Too bad, but no reason to not mark this as the answer for now :)

Comment: the `-p` flag also works with `docker-compose -p NAME run SERVICE`. For Ports you could use a different compose file and mask the first as you have done in your question code.